# Google Analytics adds additional slash after domain when opening a page

Tags: google-analytics, url

In *Content* → *Overview* you can see a table listing all visited pages of your tracked site. Next to the URL path there is a little icon:

[image]

If you click it, a popup loading the corresponding page is opened.

However, instead of `example.com/page/2` (the real URL), it opens `example.com//page/2` (notice the double slash), which returns a 404.

Why is that? How can I fix it?

In Property settings, my site default URL is noted *without* a trailing slash (`http://example.com`). I had a trailing slash there before, removed it, but it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the Website URL in the [Profile Settings](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en&pli=1#management/Profile/) doesn't have a trailing slash.

Th urls on the report links are created with the configured profile Website URL + the page path. So you probably have a trailing slash there.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Didn't find this setting before (I only found "Property settings" where is also a Website URL field).

Comment: 7 years later and this configuration bug is still biting.

Answer (score 0):

This setting is now (2022) located at **[Admin (settings)](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/#/admin)/view settings** in Google Analytics.